# Error in SQL syntax on update query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a table in my database. What makes this weird is that it actually updates, but i get an error

The code is:

```
    if ($this->id_member != null) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_member`
                        SET `status` = 1
                        WHERE `id_member` = {$this->id_member};";
                // echo $sql;
                $result = $this->database->query($sql);
}
```

Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3{"status":"success"}

I tried using the backslashes on my column and table name but the error still comes up. I have checked questions here on stackoverflow related to this but none of them could solve my issue. 
Thanks

The result of echo $sql is

```
UPDATE `tbl_member`
                    SET `status` = 1
                    WHERE `id_member` = 96;{"status":"success"}
```

The ajax side of this is

```
function activateSubscriber() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../system/components/subscribers/controller/activate_subscriber.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#activate_subscriber_form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                $('#activate_subscriber_modal').modal('hide');
                getMemberList();
                $.notify({
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Subscriber was successfully activated.',
                }, {
                    type: 'success'
                });
            } else {
                $.notify({
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
                    title: 'Failed',
                    message: 'Subscriber was NOT successfully activated.',
                }, {
                    type: 'danger'
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The controller is:

```
<?php

include('../../../config.php');
require('../../../classes/mysql.php');
include('../model/member.php');

$subscriber = new member($_POST['id_member'], $db_data);
$subscriber_result = $subscriber->activateSubscriber();
echo(json_encode($subscriber_result))
```

;

Model is

```
public function activateSubscriber() {
        try {
            if ($this->id_member != null) {
                $sql = "UPDATE tbl_member SET status = 1 WHERE id_member = {$this->id_member}";
                // echo $sql;
                $result = $this->database->query($sql);

                if ($result) {
                    return array('status' => 'success');
                } else {
                    return array('status' => 'failed');
                }
            } else {
                return array(
                    'error' => "id_member can't be null."
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage() . '  Errror!!';
        }
    }
```

Comment: {$this->id_member}; try to throw that ; away

Comment: you mean the ;  ?

Comment: `WHERE `id_member` = {$this->id_member};";` to WHERE `id_member` = {$this->id_member}";

Comment: what is the type of `status` field?

Comment: Show us result of `echo $sql`

Comment: @mith status is varchar

Comment: TRY  status = '1' .

Comment: Show us result of `var_dump($this->id_member);`

Comment: var_dump is   "96"

Comment: So result from `echo $sql` is incorrect, you must concatenate something after `$sql = "...";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `status` is varchar put it's value in single quotes  `'`
Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_member`
                    SET `status` = '1'
                    WHERE `id_member` = {$this->id_member}";
```

Comment: my bad @ mith status is tinyint

Comment: `echo $sql` showing `{"status":"success"}` with query ? @PhpDev

Comment: {"status":"success"} is the json response

Comment: Ok. then try $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_member`
                    SET `status` = 1
                    WHERE `id_member` = {$this->id_member}"; @PhpDev

Comment: can you please post your ajax/javascript code which is executing the above process?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ($this->id_member != null) {
            $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_member`
                    SET `status` = 1
                    WHERE `id_member` = ".$this->id_member;
            // echo $sql;
            $result = $this->database->query($sql); }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this( Add async:false) to your ajax call and check.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../system/components/subscribers/controller/activate_subscriber.php",
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        ...
});
```

Comment: Can u check what is the value being posted to "$_POST['id_member']"?

Comment: its the member id, which is 96. it comes as 96

Answer (score 0):

i finally fixed the problem. This is quite funny. In my construct function, i had a function which retrieved the current member details. There was a field that no longer existed in my database. It was stuck trying to retrieve the value for the non-existent field in my while loop.

Thank you everyone for the help and assistance. I appreciate!!